How to use the NGRX selectors inside an interceptor without deprecated commands
In my app I created by using Angular 17 I have a very simple interceptor:


import { HttpInterceptorFn } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpBodyModel } from "../models/http-body.model";

export const authInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {

  let reqBody = req.body as HttpBodyModel
  const reqCopy = req.clone(
    {
      headers: req.headers
        .append('Authorization', reqBody.action == 'User/login' ? '' : '' + localStorage.getItem('token'))
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')}
  )
  return next(reqCopy);
};



As you can see, it intercepts all the http call and, if the call is different from a login, search for a token in the local storage and attach the token to the header of call. As it is, it works correctly.
Now, as I am using a NGRX store, I would like to avoid the use of local / session storage and I would like to take that token directly from the store by using a NGRX selector selectUser. How can I do it?
All the example I found in the web used the "map", which is deprecated; I would like to use a code which is without deprecated parts, and I would like to use the same syntax with the HttpInterceptorFn. How can I do it?

Just inject the store into it and use you selector to get it. Then return the value as an observable.
You probably needs to makes some changes to the example code below and test it. But hopefully it would give you a general idea.
To make sure that the observable close you could use something like take operator. There is other options too.
import { HttpInterceptorFn } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpBodyModel } from "../models/http-body.model";
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';

export const authInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {
  const store = inject(Store);
  return store.select(YourTokenSelector).pipe(
    take(1),
    mergeMap(token=>{
      let reqBody = req.body as HttpBodyModel
      const reqCopy = req.clone({
          headers: req.headers
            .append('Authorization', reqBody.action == 'User/login' ? '' : '' +  token)
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      })
      return next(reqCopy);
    }));
 };


Thank you very much, exactly what I need! Just, in this way, this code creates an infinite loop of calls. Why? How can I fix it?

@Archimede i updated the post, you can use operator like take.

Please not depending on how you setup the selector, might miss the correct first value. During setting up store with initial values. you could check for the token and add it then take(1) should be fine, if its handled later, you might need to use a model where you can check if its been set yet, if that is the case you can use the filter operator before this and only trigger van value ahs been checked even if a token is available or not.
